# Atmosphere Framework: Invalid lookup class org.atmosphere.plugin.hazelcast.HazelcastBroadcaster exception

Tags: java, atmosphere

This question is regarding Atmosphere framework.

I am trying to broadcast a message to clients as soon as any event occurs (i.e. Notification).
I am not able to get Hazelcast broadcaster to work for publishing data from server to cliens. I tried using following hazelcast broadcaster implementation (atmosphere-hazelcast-2.3.0-RC5.jar).

https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere-extensions/blob/master/hazelcast/modules/src/main/java/org/atmosphere/plugin/hazelcast/HazelcastBroadcaster.java

Atmosphere automatically detects atmosphere-hazelcast-2.3.0-RC5.jar file when put in classpath. Hazelcast instance starts properly when I start my Tomcat 7.

But as soon as a call is made to factory.lookup(uniqueId) to lookup for topic to broadcast message, I get following exception:

Exception in thread "Thread-3" java.lang.IllegalStateException: Invalid lookup class org.atmosphere.plugin.hazelcast.HazelcastBroadcaster. Cached class is: org.atmosphere.cpr.DefaultBroadcaster

I am getting the broadcaster object as follows:

```
        AtmosphereFramework framework = (AtmosphereFramework) getServletContext().getAttribute("AtmosphereServlet");
        BroadcasterFactory bf = framework.getBroadcasterFactory();
        Broadcaster b = bf.lookup(uniqueId);
```

Is this the correct way to get the broadcaster in a simple servlet or one must use @Inject to inject broadcaster? (In case of simple servlet I am not sure how to use @Inject to inject a broadcaster).

Note that if I do not use HazelcastBroadcaster, then factory.lookup(uniqueId) call works well (Using default broadcaster) and messages are sent to client.

Has anybody faced similar issue? Will appriciate any pointers to solve this.

Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a bug to me with 2.3.x-RCx. Please file an issue https://github.com/Atmosphere/atmosphere

-- Jeanfrancois